# I'm wondering what is the difference between ui and common inside components folder in vercel/commerce next.js example source code?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, conventions

I try to follow vercel next.js example folder structure, but don't know what is the difference between ui and common inside components folder in vercel/commerce next.js example source code.

It seems that UI is an atomic styled component that is a reusable building block, and Common is a component that is build using what have been defined in UI folder but used everywhere too.

This is the source code: 
https://github.com/vercel/commerce/tree/main/site/components/common

Comment: Please copy and paste code here instead of giving a link. This is because code on other sites can change over time.

Answer (score 2):

That is a great question! I am also developing on top of Next.js Commerce, and I find that they don't provide any specific documentation for the custom hooks, schema (API) and the overall structure of the project.

> It seems that UI is an atomic styled component that is a reusable
> building block, and Common is a component that is build using what
> have been defined in UI folder but used everywhere too.

You are right!

Essentially in the `components/ui` folder, you will find all the components that comprise of the UI design of the application & are used repeatedly over the website. For example, button, link, grid, dropdown, input...

In the `components/common` folder though, you will find components that are also used repeatedly throughout the application, and are not single elements like the UI ones (button, link, input...). Instead, they are a combination of UI components with additional functionality, that are also meant to be used in various places through the code (e.g. avatar, footer...)

Hope my answer was clear!